# How do I ask the user to "play again" and rerun the do while loop with a simple yes or no question?

Tags: java

So I added the yes or no statement prints out but it doesn't allow the user to type it in. How do I fix that and can I nest a while loop inside a do-while loop?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HiLo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX = 100;
        int answer = random.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
        int guess = -1;
        int numberOfGuesses = 0;
        String cont;

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and " + MAX + ": ");

        do {
            while (guess != answer) {
                numberOfGuesses++;
                guess = input.nextInt();

                if (guess == 101) {
                    break;
                } else if (guess > answer) {
                    System.out.println("Too High");
                    System.out.println("\nGuess again ");
                } else if (guess < answer) {
                    System.out.println("Too Low");
                    System.out.println("\nGuess again: ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Correct! The number was " + answer + ".");
                    System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfGuesses + " guesses.");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again (yes/no)?");
            cont = input.nextLine();
        } while (cont.equals("yes");

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: `Scanner`s have a lot of little caveats. You do nextInt and it leaves a newline character in the buffer. You do nextLine, and it returns immediately with the remaining input (probably a blank line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I look to your looping logic it could be maintained and working as charm, you just need to move the initialization steps from the outside, to the inside `do-while` loop, in the beginning.

That way, at each start of the game, everything will work.

Also you're forgetting to go to next line before reading the user choice of `yes/no`, as you were reading just `int`s, at the end your a line ahead of the line containing the verdict `yes/no`

I tried this code in an online compiler, and it's working :

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){

        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX = 100;

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and " + MAX + ": ");
        String cont = new String();
        do {
            System.out.println("Let's play");
            //Initializations here
            int answer = random.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
            int guess = -1;
            int numberOfGuesses = 0;


            while (guess != answer) {
                numberOfGuesses++;
                guess = input.nextInt();

                if (guess == 101) {
                    break;
                } else if (guess > answer) {
                    System.out.println("Too High");
                    System.out.println("\nGuess again ");
                } else if (guess < answer) {
                    System.out.println("Too Low");
                    System.out.println("\nGuess again: ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Correct! The number was " + answer + ".");
                    System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfGuesses + " guesses.");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again (yes/no)?");
            input.nextLine();//You have to go to the next line...
            cont = input.nextLine();
        } while (cont.equals("yes"));
        System.out.println("\nThanks for playing !");
        input.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: Glad that I helped you sir. Just mark it as correct answer if you see that it is. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I tried it, and it fixes one of the problems I had which is great (allows the user to type a yes or no). But it doesn't loop back and restart the program, can you help me fix that?

Comment: I tried it in different online interpreters and it's working, I just added a message telling you to play again when you type `yes` to prove that it's iterating again.

Comment: So basically if the user quits the program or guesses the number correctly, the program will prompt the user if they want to play again with a yes or no question. Then it takes in the response and if the response is yes, the game should start again. The problem is that even if I type yes, it keeps asking me whether I want to play again.

Comment: I think that you're using other code than mine sir ! Be sure to use the one I provided.

Comment: @AshwatthaShinde I have this working, see the last statement of the `play` method in [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61086488/1762224).

Comment: Ok, ill try it again. I might have typed something wrong.

Comment: @IlSaggioVecchino Yeah it's working. My bad, I might have done something wrong. Thanks for your help man, I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome sir ! Just don't forget the "correct answer"

Answer (score 0):

I would organize this into a class with methods first. This breaks down each piece of logic and makes it easier to read.

1. Start a "play" loop
2. Inside the "play" loop, have a "guess" loop
3. Store the "continue" state in a known constant
4. Only check if they are correct after they made the max number of guesses.
5. Seed the `Random` object with the current system time

Also, I added a `DEBUG` flag to display the answer.

**Update:** The program is ignoring or not even asking for your "yes" input, because you were previously asking it for integers. You will need to clear/flush/reset the scanner's buffer by calling `nextLine`. Switching from integer to string leaves some data in the buffer. So your program will use the left-over character data in the buffer before it prompts you for your input.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HiLo implements Runnable {
    private static boolean DEBUG = true; // Disable to not show the answer...
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 100;
    private static final int MAX_GUESSES = 5;
    private static final String YES = "YES";

    private final Random rand;

    public HiLo() {
        this.rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new HiLo()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cont = "";
        do {
            play(scan);
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to play again (yes/no)? ");
            cont = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        } while (cont.equalsIgnoreCase(YES));
        scan.close();
    }

    public void play(Scanner scan) {
        boolean correct = false;
        int numberOfGuesses = 0;
        int answer = rand.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER) + 1;

        if (DEBUG) System.out.printf("The answer is: %d%n", answer);

        System.out.printf("Guess a number between 1 and %d%n", MAX_NUMBER);

        while (numberOfGuesses < MAX_GUESSES && !correct) {
            numberOfGuesses++;
            correct = makeGuess(scan, answer, numberOfGuesses);
        }

        if (numberOfGuesses <= MAX_GUESSES && correct) {
            System.out.printf("Correct! The number was %d. It took you %d guesses.%n", answer, numberOfGuesses);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Sorry, but you did not guess: %d", answer);
        }
        scan.nextLine(); // Reset...
    }

    public boolean makeGuess(Scanner scan, int answer, int currentGuesses) {
        System.out.print("Guess: ");
        int guess = scan.nextInt();

        if (guess == answer) {
            return true;
        }

        if (currentGuesses < MAX_GUESSES) {
            if (guess > answer) {
                System.out.print("Too High, ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Too Low, ");
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

### Sample Output

```
The answer is: 64
Guess a number between 1 and 100
Guess: 50
Too Low, Guess: 75
Too High, Guess: 60
Too Low, Guess: 65
Too High, Guess: 64
Correct! The number was 64. It took you 5 guesses.

Would you like to play again (yes/no)? yes

The answer is: 88
Guess a number between 1 and 100
Guess: 50
Too Low, Guess: 90
Too High, Guess: 80
Too Low, Guess: 85
Too Low, Guess: 87
Sorry, but you did not guess: 88

Would you like to play again (yes/no)? no
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question what does the @override do?

Comment: @AshwatthaShinde The `@Override` annotation just lets the compiler or anyone viewing the code know that the method is being implemented or overridden from its interface or parent class. For more info see: [Predefined Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) I chose to implement the `Runnable` class (which has a `run` method), but you do not really need to do this. It just makes the class look better in terms of flow.

Comment: You could get rid of the `Runnable` interface, remove the `Override` annotation, and replace the main body with `new HiLo().run()` and it would still work. All I really did was just start the program on a new thread.